# Character class in egrep called from Perl isn't recognized

Tags: perl, class, grep, character

**emphasized text**I am using egrep and character classes as shown below. The character class `[aã]` doesn't work unless I use `(a|ã)`. What am I doing wrong?

```
my @rows = `egrep --no-group-separator -r -i -I -H -A1 "^name#.*?jo[aã]o.*?#.*?#.*?#.*?#.*?\$" .`;
```

The files being searched are in UTF-8 format. Is that a problem?

This is the line that I am trying to match. I use special characters with diacritics. The file was converted from CP1252 to UTF-8 using the iconv command in linux.

name#**João** Álvares Batista#1751#José Álvares Vieira#Joana Rodrigues Barbosa#Maria da Conceição#bat.#101#http##

This is my original code:
    my @rows = `egrep --include="image_args_search_*.txt" --no-group-separator -r -i -I -H -A1 "$operator" .`;

where $operator is: **^name#.*?j[OÔÒÓÕÖoòóôõö][AÀÁÂÃÄaàáâãä][OÔÒÓÕÖoòóôõö].*?#.*?#.*?#.*?#.*?\$**

I think the problem is that the characters with accents in the egrep command are not matching the strings in the UTF-8 format files. How do I fix that?

Thanks,

Marc

Comment: could you kindly edit your question with a small piece of your input? It doesn't really make sense to be using `egrep` within a Perl script...

Answer (score -1):

This is the solution. I had to add LANG=en_US.UTF-8 in front of the command as shown below:

```
my @rows = `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 grep --include="image_args_search_*.txt" --no-group-separator -P -r -i -I -H -A1 "$operator" .`;
```